# IconState.plist Retrieval

Tags: iphone, icons, mdm

I have a question regarding to App icon position on the phone and I found out Apple stores the icon position in a plist called IconState.

In order to retrieve this plist, you could find it in the backup file from iTunes. I am wondering if I can get the plist via wifi? Perhaps like MDM sort of the way.

Thank you in advance!